# How can I fill this region?

Tags: plotting, functions, fitting

How can I fill this region?

[image]

```
Plot[{x^2, x^2 - 2 x + 1}, {x, -2, 2},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 0.5}}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adopt the advices by @BobHanlon, @Syed and @bmf, Thanks!

```
Plot[{x^2, x^2 - 2 x + 1, 
  ConditionalExpression[Min[x^2, x^2 - 2 x + 1], 
   0 <= x <= 1]}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 0.5}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Filling -> {3 -> {Axis, Directive[Red, HatchFilling[Pi/3, 1, 8]]}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: oh, that is a nice trick!

Comment: Would it be possible to not fill the boundary?

Comment: The boundary is still filled in my PC (I meant the boundary by the two first functions).

Comment: @hana  Set `PlotStyle->None` to the third curve.

Comment: +1 Alternatively, `ConditionalExpression[Min[x^2, x^2 - 2 x + 1], 0 <= x <= 1]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks!

Comment: Add `Exclusions -> None`

Comment: @cvgmt it was a (+1) from me but it just occurred to me. You can use `FillingStyle -> {3 -> HatchFilling[Pi/3]}` to make the picture for the`Filling` closer to the OP depiction.

Comment: @bmf Thanks,updated. We can also use `Filling -> {3 -> {Axis, HatchFilling[Pi/3]}}`.